# Using quotes inside html attribute

Tags: php, javascript, html

I haven't coded with PHP in a while and cannot remember how to do this..

I'm using a jquery plugin that requires some rel parameters to be set.

```
    $imgtag = '<a href="'.carturl($img->id,'images').'/'.$img->filename.'" class = "zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, zoomWidth:150, zoomHeight:150">
<img src="'.$src.'"'.$titleattr.' alt="'.$alt.'" width="'.$width_a.'" height="'.$height_a.'" '.$classes.' /></a>';
```

Now I need to add `, position: "inside"` to the rel bit, however, every time I do it, it outputs in HTML as quotes all over the place. The plugin must retail the quotes around the word "inside" to work, however, I need to use these quotes within the "rel=" quotes.

How do I go about this?

HTML Output should look like this:

```
    <a style="position: relative; display: block;" href="http://www.URL.com/theimage.jpg" class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, zoomWidth:150, zoomHeight:150, position:"inside"">
<img style="display: block;" src="http://www.URL.com/theimage.jpg" alt="product-picture" height="450" width="360"></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure there should be quotes in position: "inside" ? can't it be just position:inside ?

Comment: @itsmeee: it has to be with quotes :( won't work without

Comment: Its actually a html issue, not php :) PHP just generates whatever html you say him to generate, so i fixed the title to be more descriptive.

Comment: `rel=what?!`: The `rel` attribute [has a defined purpose](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-rel) and that purpose is not "Store arbitrary data for JavaScript to read" (which is what [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) is for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
 $imgtag = '<a href="'.carturl($img->id,'images').'/'.$img->filename.'" class = "zoom" id="zoom1" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, zoomWidth:150, zoomHeight:150, position:\'inside\' ">
<img src="'.$src.'"'.$titleattr.' alt="'.$alt.'" width="'.$width_a.'" height="'.$height_a.'" '.$classes.' /></a>';
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you so much. I'll accept this answer in 5 mins ;)

Answer (score 2):

use single quote

```
rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, zoomWidth:150, zoomHeight:150, position:'inside'"
```

or reverse

```
rel='adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4, zoomWidth:150, zoomHeight:150, position:"inside"'
```

Comment: @MartinH23 Ahh, its all inside php echo statement? Ohwell, do it like `rel="..., position:\'inside\'"`. You have to escape special characters

Comment: Thanks Janis, all sorted as per above.

Answer (score -1):

You can escape quotes using the following syntax:

```
\"your stuff\"
```

This will render wrapped in ", assuming you have also the outer quotes round the rel element

Comment: Tried this earlier.. outputs as: position:\" inside\""="">

Comment: possibly because your string is enclosed with single quotes, start it with " and the inside use \" to represent the quotes so an example would be $var = "<img src=\"aURL\"/>";

Comment: Nope, you can’t escape characters by preceding them with a backslash in HTML. You might be thinking of JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: I'm thinking of PHP as per the original post where you can happily write $somit = "text \"" . $var . "\" more text"; with the \" replacing ' if you so choose